# How to convert string to number and vice versa in Excel

Tags: string, vba, excel, type-conversion

I have some XML files that contain decimal numbers stored with '.' as decimal separator. I created Excel workbook that is used for editing data in that XML. MSXML is used to read the data from XML that are then displayed in worksheets. Once data is being stored I modify DOM structure with new values read from tables and I save XML.

The problem is that when I convert decimal numbers back to strings, to save them as values in XML, decimal separator that is specified by user in Windows regional settings is used.

I need a way to force storing decimal numbers with '.' as decimal separator in all cases. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How do you modify the DOM structure with the new values--programmatically? How?

Is it possible for you to use `Format(Cell.value, "#0.0")`? Also try `Format(CDbl(Cell.Value), "#0.0")`. If that doesn't work, can you just throw in a `Replace(Value, ",", ".")`? This should be okay if you're not using thousands separators.

Comment: I just do xmlNode.Text = cell.Value. I tried your suggestion but the result still has "," as decimal separator.

Comment: Using Replace is my final solution. I just need to make sure that there are no numbers that contain both decimal and thousands separator using Format function.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Str` function. It recognizes only the period `.` as a valid decimal separator.

```
Dim d as Double
Dim s as String
d = 3.25
s = Str(d) 
' s is now " 3.25"
```

Note that `Str` reserves a leading space for the sign of the number. If you don't want a leading space on your positive numbers, just `Trim` the result:

```
s = Trim(Str(d))
' s is now "3.25"
```

Comment: I had problems getting this to work in both directions, and I need to be able to both read and write XML values. I have this code for reading now
`If CDbl("1.000") = 1000 Then 
    num = CDbl(Replace(value, ".", ","))
Else
    num = CDbl(value)
End If`

Comment: You didn't ask for something that works in both directions... But your solution looks like it is a good way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

@Jean-Francois since we're talking about i18n you should use **CStr** ( for international applications ) function instead of **Str** ( where . dot is separator for floating number , not much use in French where comma , is a separator ex : 7,54)

```
Sub myFunction()
    Dim num As Double
    Dim str As String

    num = 3.251
    str = CStr(num) ' convert a number into a String

    num = Val(str) ' convert a String into an integer
    num = Trim(str) ' convert a String into a Variant

    str = Trim(num) ' notice this works the other way around

End Sub
```

Comment: Question says: "I need a way to force storing decimal numbers with `.` as decimal separator in all cases". That's what my answer does.